# Direct proof that the space of endpoints of the Lelek fan is almost zero-dimensional

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis, continuum-theory

I'm interested in the proof that space of endpoints of the Lelek fan is almost zero-dimensional. As much is claimed in *On homogeneous totally disconnected 1-dimensional spaces* by Kawamura, Oversteegen, Tymchatyn, where they say that the proof is easy and reference *A Topological Characterization of R-Trees* by Mayer, Oversteegen in which no such thing is proved.

Some context: A space $X$ is *almost zero-dimensional* if there exists a basis $\mathcal B$ of open sets such that for all $U \in \mathcal B$ the complement of the closure of $B$ is a union of clopen sets.
The *Lelek fan* $L$ is the unique smooth fan with a dense set $E(L)$ of endpoints. Consider $E(L)$ with the induced topology.

I'd like a description of a basis which witnesses the almost zero-dimensionality of $E(L)$.